# Change navigation bar color on Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

In every program I write on Delphi for Android the navigation bar is white and no transparent.
I have a Galaxy A50 for test, with dark mode enabled.
How can I change the color or the transparency on navigation bar.
I don't know what is wrong. The mobile, Delphi or the AndroidManifest.
I don't know what to try (except the Form.Fullscreen).
[sample screenshot](http://xocivy.club/Screenshot_20200719-124054.jpg)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

uses -> Androidapi.Helpers;

when creating the form -> TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.setNavigationBarColor(TAlphaColor($FF6A8FC3));